# Background image in component cover full browser

Tags: html, css, angular

Ok guys i'm a bit confused here.

I'm working with AngularJs and trying to set a background image for one particular component, not for the whole app.
And trying for it to cover the full extend of the browser. Right now it's leaving a blank space at the bottom (2) of it and with larger screens this white space is bigger.

[As you can see in the image (the background image (1) gets cut where the container ends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN92o.jpg)

Purple line is just a border to show the container.

Component Css

```
.align-text-message{
    text-align: center;
}

.content-data{
    margin-left: 3%; 
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.fondo_seccion{
    background-image: url("../../assets/img/fondo_datos.png");
    height: auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 0.75%;
}

.menu-dashboard{
    opacity: 0.9; 
    margin-top: -2%;
}

.infoUser{
    margin-top: 4%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .content-data{
        margin-left: 0%;
        margin-top: 15%;
        z-index: -1;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .menu-dashboard{
        min-height: auto;
    }
}
```

Component HTML

```
<div class="infoUser">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 menu-dashboard">
      <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row fondo_seccion">
    <div class="col-md-11 content-data">

      <div class="form-group" [hidden]="!basicLevelFormComponent.userNoInfo">
        <div class="alert alert-warning align-text-message" role="alert">
          ¡A&uacute;n no ha ingresado su informaci&oacute;n!
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" [hidden]="!basicLevelFormComponent.fatalError">
        <div class="alert alert-danger align-text-message" role="alert">
          ¡No hemos podido cargar su informaci&oacute;n!
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" [hidden]="!basicLevelFormComponent.infoSuccess">
        <div class="alert alert-success align-text-message" role="alert">
          ¡Informaci&oacute;n actualizada!
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" [hidden]="!basicLevelFormComponent.userNotify">
        <div class="alert alert-warning align-text-message" role="alert">
          {{basicLevelFormComponent.messageNotify}}
        </div>
      </div>

      <app-basic-level-form [hidden]="!showBasicLevelForm"></app-basic-level-form>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One of the things i tried is to swap fondo_seccion from where it's right now to the DIV where infoUser is but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any element that you want to cover the whole height of the browser screen would need to be height:100% not auto. However for this to work HTML, BODY and any other parent container of that element would also need to be height: 100%.

So fondo_seccion and infoUser would both need to be set to height:100% along with any parent divs and html and body.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.fondo_seccion{
    background-image: url("../../assets/img/fondo_datos.png");
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 0.75%;
}

.infoUser{
    margin-top: 4%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I understand now how it works.